# Dishonored Definitive Edition(EPIC) changing the INI files doesn't affect the game, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: dishonored

I've been playing the game for a while, finished it several times, completed challenges, and so on.

Now I want to make some changes to it, just to experiment with stuff.
For example, I've tried changing the Bend Time power from 8 to 600 seconds, as I was told there's a "DishonoredPower.ini" file where I can do that. I had a "default" instead of the "dishonored" ini, so I changed that but nothing happened. I copied and renamed it to "dishonored", still: nothing changed.

What could be the problem? Is it even possible to change power durations?

Comment: Have you tried setting the file to 'read-only'?

Comment: even tho the content of the file doesn't change after I changed it, yes.

Comment: So you mean it won't save your edits? Then that must be the problem, right?

Comment: No. Sorry for my bad English. I meant this: The values were set to: 2.5. I set it to 255. I started the game. The value stayed 255. I quit, it stayed 255. You know what I mean? The game itself didn't change it after I changed it.

Comment: And you are sure you have the right file and the right value? Could it be too high for the engine to take into account, so it refers to the default value? Have you tried different values? Could there be more files where that value is stored? (Oh, and no need to apologize for your English :)

Comment: I tried these values/ default was 2.5, went to 255,100,40,20 and 10. None worked. I'll get home around 6PM,I'll update the question with the mentioned ini's content and locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ini files starting with "Default" in Unreal Engine 3 games (such as Dishonored) are typically just used to generate user-specific ini files. After those files are generated, the defaults aren't used again unless the user-specific files are deleted.

On my machine, user-specific files are located at `Documents/my games/Dishonored/DishonoredGame/Config`. This is where `DishonoredPower.ini` lives. I didn't have a chance to test it, but there's a good chance this is the file which you need to modify.

Comment: As I mentioned "I had a "default" instead of the "dishonored" ini, so I changed that but nothing happened. I copied and renamed it to "dishonored", still: nothing changed. ", so I had no dishonoredpower.ini in that folder. This is why I came here. I have others, like dishonoredgame and dishonoredengine ini, but the power one. And even if i copied and rneamed the copy to dishonoredpower, it wouldn't change anything,sadly.

Comment: @ADHDisDEV Did you try the file location I mentioned?

Comment: I don't know how to make this even more clear, but Yes. And still: nothing changed. As I mentioned several times again, we're looking at the same file, I've tried different values, etc...

Comment: It's okay. I delete the game in any minute now and just give up trying to modify/mod/change anything. I give up.